# How do I delete a record in my javascript to do list?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a to do list and I'm trying to create a delete button that will prompt an id number to delete a record. You pick which record you want to delete. Not sure how to go about doing it. This code has the html in it as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>To Do List</title>
    <style>
        body{margin:20px;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var list;
    var addBtn;
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",load);
    function load(){
        list = get("list");
        checkboxes = getTag("input");
        addBtn = get("addBtn");
        addBtn.addEventListener("click",addItem);
        for(var i = 0, l = checkboxes.length; i < l ; i++){
            if(checkboxes[i].type == "checkbox")
                checkboxes[i].addEventListener("click",updatePercent);
        }
        if(localStorage.listFile)
            //list.innerHTML = localStorage.listFile;
        updatePercent();
    }
    function updatePercent(){
        var checkboxes = getTag("input");
        var total = checkboxes.length/2;
        var done = 0;
        for(var i = 0, l = checkboxes.length; i < l ; i++){
            if(checkboxes[i].checked)
                done++;
        }
        get("percentage").innerHTML = "Done: " + Math.round((done/total)*100) + "%";
    }
    function addItem(){
        var item = document.createElement('li');
        var chk = document.createElement("input");
        var txt = document.createElement("input");
        chk.type = "checkbox";
        txt.type = "text";
        chk.addEventListener("click",updatePercent);
        item.appendChild(chk);
        item.appendChild(txt);
        list.appendChild(item);
        updatePercent();
    }
    function get(id){
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }
    function getTag(tag){
        return document.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    }
    function save(){
        localStorage.listFile = list.innerHTML;
    }
    function deleteTsk(){
        var i = prompt("Enter number you want to delete") - 1;
        //checkboxes[i].splice(i,1);
        checkboxes[i].innerHTML = "";
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Kung Fu To Do List 1.0</h1>
    <ol id="list">
        <li><input type="checkbox"><input type="text"></li>
    </ol>
    <p id="percentage"></p>
    <button id="addBtn">Add Item</button><button onclick="save()">Save</button><button onclick="deleteTsk()">Delete</button>
</body>
```

I figured out how to delete it with this method.

```
function deleteTsk(){
        var i = prompt("Enter number you want to delete") - 1;
        var item = getTag("li");
        list.removeChild(item[i]);
    }
```

Comment: I would expect to check the item I wanted to delete, not to type the ID of it

Comment: no you check the tasks that you complete but I don't have a way of deleting the record. By the way this also keeps track of percent done.

Comment: I understand, but it is not logical. Use a toggled image with a checkmark like here at SO to complete and use the checkbox to select items to process (like bulk complete too)

Comment: That would be better but I'm not I'm not sure what I'm doing. I figured out how to delete the element. I used the removeChild method and it worked great and didn't break the updatePercentage method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to delete it with this method.

```
function deleteTsk(){
        var i = prompt("Enter number you want to delete") - 1;
        var item = getTag("li");
        list.removeChild(item[i]);
    }
```